# How to Partition by Reference in Oracle 19c IDE (Intellij)?

Tags: intellij-idea, oracle-sqldeveloper, partitioning, database-partitioning, oracle19c

Is "partition by reference" not supported in Oracle 19c?

For some reason, my IDE (Intellij) keeps complaining when I try to partition by reference when creating a table, saying:
" HASH, LIST, RANGE, SQL_REFERENCE or SYSTEM expected, got 'REFERENCE' "

I checked the Oracle version, this is Oracle 19c.

I tried partition by list, this works.

I tried creating the parent table and the child table both with the primary and foreign key defined as table constraints instead of column constraint. Does not work.

I tried the example I found here:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  order_date  DATE NOT NULL,
  customer_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  shipper_id  NUMBER)
PARTITION BY RANGE (order_date) (
  PARTITION y1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2006', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
  PARTITION y2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2007', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
  PARTITION y3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008', 'DD-MON-YYYY')));

CREATE TABLE order_items (
  order_id    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  product_id  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  price       NUMBER,
  quantity    NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT order_items_fk FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE (order_items_fk);
```

This does not work either...

**But is DOES work in Oracle SQL Developer!**

What is causing this?
Probably some very stupid mistake? (I hope)

Comment: and where is your create table statements? What is the specific error?  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: @OldProgrammer, sorry, link did not work. Added some new info too.

Comment: sounds like a bug in intellij.  Report to them.